# How to use Confidentical transfer USDT?

Tags: token-2022

I want to use Confidentical transfer USDT or USDC for privacy. I want to know does it support on solana testnet?The offical document seems not finish.

Answer (score 1):

USDT and USDC do *not* support confidential transfers. You will have to create a new mint with confidential transfers enabled and wrap USDC or USDT with a separate smart contract yourself if you want this functionality.

Or you can create your own stablecoin with confidential transfers enabled!